# Having trouble with second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a Nvidia Geforce GT 640 1 GB.

I set up another monitor and it worked fine for about fifteen minutes, the screen is now black but still shows up in my display settings. I can interact with windows on the second monitor but i cant see them.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

flip-flop the monitor's connections on the video card... does the problem follow the monitor or port? If it follows the monitor, you likely have a bad monitor, if it follows the port, you have a bad video card or misconfiguration.